# Salvar dados de formulário em TXT (PHP)

Tags: php, formulário, txt

Olá, boa tarde!
Tenho o seguintes código:

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST['texto'])) {
   $texto = $_POST['texto'];

   $arquivo = fopen('msg.txt', 'w');
   fwrite($arquivo, $texto);
   fclose($arquivo);
}
?>
```

Que deveria funcionar junto com esse:

```
<form method="post">
             <span style="font-family:lucida sans unicode,lucida grande,sans-serif">login:</span>
               <input type="text" name="texto" style="height: 40px">
             </span>Senha:</span>
            <input type="password" name="texto" style="height: 40px"><br></font>
            <button style="width:90px, height:40px">Enviar</button></center>
         </form>
```

Por que, ele não escreve a senha também em TXT?? ele só salva um campo do formulário em TXT.

Gostaria que o código salva-se todos os campos do formulário em TXT, e também gostaria de fazer o seguinte, ele vai salvar msg.txt ... quando a próxima pessoa for fazer ele identificar que já existe um msg.txt e criar um msg2.txt pra não sobrescrever o primeiro, como faz??

Comment: Faça um tour para ter uma visão rápida do site https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Se alguma resposta resolveu seu problema marque-a como aceita, veja como https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png

Answer (score 1):

Por que, ele não escreve a senha também em TXT??

Para pegar todos os valores dos inputs que tem o mesmo nome é preciso adicionar colchetes no atributo `name` exemplo `name="texto[]"`, dessa forma quando chegar no PHP esses campos chegarão como um array.

```
<input type="text" name="texto[]" style="height: 40px">
<input type="password" name="texto[]" style="height: 40px">
```

Você também pode dar `names` diferentes para os campos, exemplo: `login` e `senha`

```
<input type="text" name="login" style="height: 40px">
<input type="password" name="senha" style="height: 40px">
```

No primeiro caso recupera valores enviados do formulário e cria o conteúdo dessa forma

```
// cria conteúdo para escrever no arquivo de texto
$textoPublicar = "login: ".$_POST['texto'][0]. " Senha: ".$_POST['texto'][1];
```

No segundo caso assim

```
// cria conteúdo para escrever no arquivo de texto
$textoPublicar= "login: ".$_POST['login']." senha: ".$_POST['senha'];
```

### Código completo comentado para o primeiro caso

```
<?php

    //mesma pasta
    $dir="";
    
    //outra pasta, caminho da pasta, exemplo
    $dir="textos/";
    
    // glob() - Retorna um array contendo todos os arquivos (*) com extensão .txt do diretorio indicado
    $array = glob($dir."*.txt");
    
    // se for um array e não vazio
    if ( is_array($array) && !empty($array) ) {
        $numeros=[];
            foreach ( $array as $val) {
                //cria um array somente com a parte numérica dos nomes dos arquivos
                $numeros[] = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $val);
            }
        
        // max() recupera o maior valor do array $numeros
        // cria o numero do proximo nome do arquivo de texto
        $numArquivo = max($numeros)+1; 
    
    }
    
    //cria o nome do arquivo de texto
    $filename = "msg".($numArquivo).".txt";
    
    
    if ( isset($_POST['texto']) && !empty($_POST['texto']) ) {
    
        // cria conteudo para escrever no arquivo de texto
        $textoPublicar = "login: ".$_POST['texto'][0]. " Senha: ".$_POST['texto'][1];
       
       //cria o arquivo e grava
       $arquivo = fopen($dir.$filename, 'w');
       fwrite($arquivo, $textoPublicar);
       fclose($arquivo);
       
    }

?>

<form method="post">
    <span style="font-family:lucida sans unicode,lucida grande,sans-serif">login:</span>
    <input type="text" name="texto[]" style="height: 40px">
    </span>Senha:</span>
    <input type="password" name="texto[]" style="height: 40px"><br></font>
    <button style="width:90px, height:40px">Enviar</button></center>
</form>
```

### Código completo comentado para o segundo caso

```
<?php

    //mesma pasta
    $dir="";
    
    //outra pasta, caminho da pasta, exemplo
    $dir="textos/";
    
    // glob() - Retorna um array contendo todos os arquivos (*) com extensão .txt do diretorio indicado
    $array = glob($dir."*.txt");
    
    // se for um array e não vazio
    if ( is_array($array) && !empty($array) ) {
        $numeros=[];
            foreach ( $array as $val) {
                //cria um array somente com a parte numérica dos nomes dos arquivos
                $numeros[] = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $val);
            }
        
        // max() recupera o maior valor do array $numeros
        // cria o numero do próximo nome do arquivo de texto
        $numArquivo = max($numeros)+1; 
    
    }
    
    //cria o nome do arquivo de texto
    $filename = "msg".($numArquivo).".txt";

    if ( isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['senha']) ) {
        
       // cria conteudo para escrever no arquivo de texto
        $textoPublicar= "login: ".$_POST['login']." senha: ".$_POST['senha'];
       
       //cria o arquivo e grava
       $arquivo = fopen($dir.$filename, 'w');
       fwrite($arquivo, $textoPublicar);
       fclose($arquivo);
       
    }
    
?>

<form method="post">
    <span style="font-family:lucida sans unicode,lucida grande,sans-serif">login:</span>
    <input type="text" name="login" style="height: 40px">
    </span>Senha:</span>
    <input type="password" name="senha" style="height: 40px"><br></font>
    <button style="width:90px, height:40px">Enviar</button></center>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde,

No caso está salvando apenas um dado, pois os dois campos estão com a tag name="texto" altera a tag do campo senha Ex:name="senha";

e altere o arquivo php para

```
   $texto = $_POST['texto'];
   $senha = $_POST['senha'];
```

caso queira a senha visível retire o password do campo e altere para text mesmo.